# WSL 2 is not installed error when opening docker desktop

Tags: docker, containers

Whenever I try to open docker desktop on windows 10, I get this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlUCn.png

But I never opted for *WSL installation* while installing docker desktop.
I tried uninstalling it, restarting my PC and removing the local APPDATA manually, but still I'm getting this error.

Comment: You can probably use CTRL+C to copy paste the error message to this question. This helps to find it and similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open powershell and use `wsl --install`. After that restart your computer and try to open docker again.

Comment: thanks! I reinstalled docker as well and it's working.

Comment: This command just hangs for me with message "Launching Ubuntu..."